# Linkings STAGES & LOAD_HISTORY tables in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I Join the following 2 tables in snowflake?

1. SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.STAGES
2. SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGES.COPY_HISTORY

STAGES has stage_name & stage_id, but COPY_HISTORY only has STAGE_LOCATION and I cant seem to link the 2 up is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score -1):

You can join the COPY_HISTORY.STAGE_LOCATION column to the STAGE.STAGE_URL column

Comment: This only works for external stages, but i need it for internal stages as well.